# AWSS3 Uploading failed with error

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to upload an image on on amazon server but every time i try to upload an image it shows me an **error** in logs.

> 016-10-08 14:37:41.741 Vabo[3091:62598] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.10 [Debug]
>       AWSURLSessionManager.m line:543 | -[AWSURLSessionManagerprintHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] 
>       Request body: 2016-10-08 14:38:44.171 Vabo[3091:62596] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.10 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:212 |
>   -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]
>
> Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>       UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/vabo/production/uploads/avatars/200/avatar.jpg,
>       _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/vabo/production/uploads/avatars/200/avatar.jpg,
>       NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ca545a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" 
>       UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}

Here is the code i am using to upload my Image.

```
func fusumaImageSelected(image: UIImage) {
    self.imageView.image = image


    let fileName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString.stringByAppendingString(".jpg")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("upload").URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let filePath = fileURL.path!
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    imageData!.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)



    let putObjectRequest = AWSS3PutObjectRequest()
    putObjectRequest.body = imageData
    putObjectRequest.contentLength = NSNumber.init(long: (imageData?.length)!)
    putObjectRequest.expires = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(3600);
    putObjectRequest.contentType = "image/png"
    putObjectRequest.key = "production/uploads/avatars/200/avatar.jpg"
    putObjectRequest.bucket = Constants.S3BucketName

    self.uploadProgessInLoading(putObjectRequest)
    AWSS3.defaultS3().putObject(putObjectRequest).continueWithBlock{(task) -> AnyObject! in

        if let error = task.error {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain as String {
                if let errorCode = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                    switch (errorCode) {
                    case .Cancelled, .Paused:
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        })
                        break;

                    default:
                        print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
                }
            } else {
                print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
            }
        }

        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("upload() failed: [\(exception)]")
        }

        if task.result != nil {

        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to follow might it be helpful for you https://github.com/SanjeetVerma/AWS-ImageUpload-Download-Objective-C

Comment: Sir this is the error occurring when i click upload button in this project.
 Error Occured  =    The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 3.)

Answer (score 1):

For me to solve this issue I had to add a bridging header and I was using the wrong region for my identity pool.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to bucket name configuration being incorrect.
The error code is described here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/d0154d3f1e1cc20fad8c7339208ee208f1d8c516/AWSS3/AWSS3Model.h

Could you please make sure the bucket name is correct in `Constants.bucketName`? You need to provide a valid bucket name in your account with permissions to do a putObject from your cognito role.

Thanks,
Rohan